# When using node sharp package to resize image and upload to s3 it is rotated

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, image-resizing, image-rotation

I am using this node package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp

I use it to resize an image and then upload it to amazon S3.

Most images are find but some of them (I assume based on aspect ratio) get rotated.

Is there a way to prevent this or a reason for it?

Here is a copy of the code I am using. imageData is either data taken from an s3 bucket file of from file upload.
As you can see I am not calling the rotate function. Is there anyway to 'lock' rotation?

```
module.exports.resize = function(imageData, width, fileName){
    sharp(imageData).resize(parseInt(width), null).toBuffer(function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;

        s3.putObject({
            Bucket: aws.bucket,
            Key: 'images/' + width + '/' + fileName,
            Body: data
        }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Failed to resize image due to an error: ' + err);
                return {
                    message: 'Failed to resize image due to an error: ' + err
                };
            } else {
                console.log('s3 image uploaded to ' + 'images/' + width + '/' + fileName);
                return {
                    message: 's3 image uploaded to ' + 'images/' + width + '/' + fileName
                };
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be better if you show your code and test image.

Comment: Is it possible that your image has EXIF orientation data that is not being taken into account by your viewer or libvips (the backing lib for sharp)?

Comment: How would I check EXIF orientation data?

Comment: Hello, sharp maintainer here. @mikefrey's comment is the most likely explanation. By default sharp removes EXIF metadata. Add `rotate()` to your processing chain to auto-rotate the image based on the EXIF metadata before it is removed.

Answer (score 7):

Working code to fetch image from url(s3 url) ,resize it and then upload the resized image to s3

```
var sharp = require('sharp')
var request = require('request').defaults({encoding: null})
var s3Upload = require('./s3Upload')

module.exports = function (fileLocation) {
  request(fileLocation, function (error, response, body) {
  var fileInstance400x400 = sharp(body)
  var inst400x400 = fileInstance400x400.resize(400, 400)
  s3Upload('filename400x400', inst400X400)
  })
}
// fileLocation iabsolute url of image
```

s3Upload module

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk')
var config = require('../config')
/**
 * @param fileName: filename to be saved
 * @param file: bufferd data
 */

function defaultContentType(req, file, cb) {
  setImmediate(function () {
    var ct = file.contentType || file.mimetype || 'application/octet-stream'
    cb(null, ct);
  });
}

module.exports = function (fileName, file) {
  aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: config.S3_CONF.access_key_id,
    secretAccessKey: config.S3_CONF.access_key,
    region: config.S3_CONF.region,
    contentType: defaultContentType,
    limits: {fileSize: 1000000, files: config.MAX_FILE_COUNT || 6}
  })

  var s3bucket = new aws.S3({params: {Bucket: config.S3_CONF.media_bucket}});

  var params = {Key: fileName, Body: file};
  // TODO setting proper header for s3
  s3bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error uploading data: ', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey');
    }
  });

}
```

hope it helps

Comment: NEVER use the accessKeyId & secretAccessKey in the code !

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov As long as the config is referencing environment variables and the function is run on a server and not on the client, then it's just fine.

Comment: No, it’s not! Because tomorrow you might expand your business, accidentally upload it to github or something similar while forgetting about the codes and you’re screwed.

Comment: The machine credentials should simply be set!